# Search for repeated strings corresponding to a values across multiple columns in python(preferably with pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of three columns which looks something like this:

```
    X1 X5 X1
    X2 X9 X2
    X3 X3 X5
    X4 X8 X3
    X5 X1 X4
```

I want to search for the variable which is present in all the columns. In this case, the output would be,

```
    X1
    X3
    X5
```

Can someone please help doing this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `.apply` `value_counts` to your columns, you'll get the following:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
    a   b   c
0  X1  X5  X1
1  X2  X9  X2
2  X3  X3  X5
3  X4  X8  X3
4  X5  X1  X4

In [26]: df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
Out[26]:
      a    b    c
X1  1.0  1.0  1.0
X2  1.0  NaN  1.0
X3  1.0  1.0  1.0
X4  1.0  NaN  1.0
X5  1.0  1.0  1.0
X8  NaN  1.0  NaN
X9  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

So, you want the rows that are all not null...

```
In [28]: result = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).notnull().all(axis=1)
In [29]: result
Out[29]:
X1     True
X2    False
X3     True
X4    False
X5     True
X8    False
X9    False
dtype: bool
```

And, you can get a `list` of the indices where the values are `True`:

```
In [30]: [i for i, x in result.iteritems() if x]
Out[30]: ['X1', 'X3', 'X5']
```

And a slightly different approach:

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
    a   b   c
0  X1  X5  X1
1  X2  X9  X2
2  X3  X3  X5
3  X4  X8  X3
4  X5  X1  X4

In [51]: uniq = pd.Series(np.unique(df.values))

In [52]: uniq
Out[52]:
0    X1
1    X2
2    X3
3    X4
4    X5
5    X8
6    X9
dtype: object

In [53]: result = df.apply(uniq.isin).all(axis=1)

In [54]: result.index = uniq

In [55]: result
Out[55]:
X1     True
X2    False
X3     True
X4    False
X5     True
X8    False
X9    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Perfect, 'result' is the one I was looking for.
Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I can imagine:
1. Make set of values in each column
2. Do sets intersection on all sets obtained in previous step

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'], 'b': ['x5', 'x9', 'x3', 'x8', 'x1'], 'c': ['x1', 'x1', 'x5', 'x3', 'x4']})

sets = [set(df[column]) for column in df.columns]
result = list(set.intersection(*sets))
```